# Create RSA Token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to authenticate to a REST API using encryption.

First I need to call the API to get an `encryptionKey` and a `timestamp`.
*The encryptionKey is in Base 64 format.*

Then I need to create a `RSAToken` using the key and finaly encrypt the password using `password + "|" + timestamp`.

This is some sample code using python to authenticate to the API

```
key, timestamp = get_encryption_key()
decoded_key = key.decode('base64')
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(decoded_key)
encrypted = rsa_key.encrypt(password + '|' + str(timestamp), 'x')
encrypted_password = encrypted[0]
```

and

```
import base64
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
r = requests.get(my_url, headers=headers)

myData = r.json()
decoded = base64.b64decode(myData['encryptionKey'])
key = RSA.importKey(decoded)
enc = key.encrypt(password + '|' + str(myData['timeStamp']), 'x')
encryptedPassword = enc[0]

session = "/session"
my_url = url + session

payload = {"identifier": identifier,
"password": encryptedPassword,
"encryptedPassword": "True"
}
```

Any hints to achieve this under Node?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit about how the API works. You say you need an "RSAToken". What exactly is this? If the API is indeed RSA based, then this might be that you need to encrypt your password and the provided timestamp under the RSA public key. In In your code however you create an AES cipher...

Comment: @ArnoMittelbach Unfortunatly there isn't any others informations in the API docs. I added some sample code I've found but it's in python. I guess the RSAToken is an RSA key ? I have no idea how all this work but I will try looking around about it

Comment: **Never use textbook RSA.** It is insecure and permits many different attacks. You should use RSA with padding such as OAEP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`crypto.publicEncrypt`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_public_key_buffer) to encrypt your password. Notice the `padding`, you might want to use the right padding that is being used in your Python script.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const constants = require('constants');
const decodedKey = Buffer(encriptionKey, 'base64').toString();

const encryptedPassword = crypto.publicEncrypt({
    key: decodedKey,
    padding : constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
} , Buffer(`${password}|${timestamp}`));
```

Check out this [node.js test](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2c97bd47e40aedf932f7f4392f446da63d679d1a/test/parallel/test-crypto-rsa-dsa.js#L109-L131) to find out more examples for different padding.